# I can't find chromium build version for stable chrome

Tags: puppeteer, chromium

I want to use stable chrome version at pptr, so i search https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/ for finding chromium build.
[image]
but build 902210 is not in  chromium browser snapshot( https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html)

is there something another way to find stable chromium build?

Comment: That version is outdated, that's why it's not visible there. Do you want to clone the repo of version `90.x`?

Comment: @Asesh i want to use pptr with stable chrome version. by using [pptr PUPPETEER_CHROMIUM_REVISION config](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v10.4.0&show=api-environment-variables)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue so here is what I found in case it helps:

On https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium, it is written "you can get a build of Chromium 44.x which should mostly match the stable release" and "sometimes you may have to decrement the commit number until you find one".

I searched the latest version number (which is currently 94.0.4606.81) on https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/ but cannot find its build number (911515, known as Branch Base Position on the previous link) on https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/.

So I decremented the number until I find one matching, like explained previously and I found 911494: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/911494/

When I downloaded this Chromium version, in "About Chromium", it displayed "Version 94.0.4606.0 (Developer Build) (64-bit)". Which almost matches 94.0.4606.81.

On https://githubmemory.com/repo/Bugazelle/chromium-all-old-stable-versions/issues/2, I read "You cannot install a stable Chromium version downloaded from chromium-browser-snapshots because there are absolutely no Chromium stable versions there." and "It is recommended to compile Chromium yourself to have a similar stable version... or find third-parties builds.".

Linux distributions like Ubuntu provide a stable Chromium package. Otherwise if we don't want to compile the stable version, we can get the closest developer version like explained previously.